# Will this cause damage to the powered USB hub plus any device that happens to be plugged into the hub?

Tags: usb, power-supply, power

I have a AC/DC Samlex 1235M converter delivering 12 plus volts to a Rigrunner power strip.   I plan to plug a powered USB Hub rated 5V, 3amp into the power strip (which will have a 3amp fuse).    Here is my concern, the 12 volt power coming from the converter - will it fry the hub (5V) and any device that is plugged into the hub?

I am trying to manage cables on my Telescope by connecting all of my powered devices (AstroCamera, Focuser, Dewheater, Mount, USB Hub) into the power strip.   And run all of my data lines (guide camera,mount,focuser, camera) into the USB hub.   The result will be one power and one data cable to mananage instead of 10)    I hope someone can make sense of this.  In short, will a 12 volt power supply fry a powered usb hub that is rated 5 volts?

Comment: It's a good bet that a 12V supply will fry devices that expect 5V.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a local 12 V to 5 VDC converter, such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MEF293V) from Amazon.

You'll also need knowledge about what devices need separate grounds or common ground connections, the total power needed, which devices need to have power applied first, etc.

Comment: Thanks!  I was afraid of that!   I guess I could find a 12 volt USB Hub and solve the problem.